# Get the content and add that content as a class

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following elements;

```
<li class="wens">
   <span class="cck">one</span>
</li>

<li class="wens">
   <span class="cck">wone</span>
</li>

<li class="wens">
   <span class="cck">senw</span>
</li>
```

I'm trying to get the content of the `.cck` and add that content as a class to its parent `<li>`

This is the code i tried, But its not working.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.wens').each(function(){
           var cckcontent = $(this).find('.cck').html();           
           $(this).addClass(cckcontent);
      });  
 });
```

Please guyz, Help me do this. Many thanks as advance.

Regard.

Comment: Unable to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/dPMzd/

Comment: I saw what you have done seems to be correct already. check http://jsfiddle.net/YD2mS/

Comment: nothing is wrong with code i have tested it..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g83PZ/)**

```
 $('.wens:has(.cck)').addClass("class-name");
```

Comment: Actually I want to add the class to the .wens. But that class should be the content of the .cck. Content inside the .cck is dynamically changing.

Comment: he want to add it to li tag

Answer (score 1):

Use the parent method:

```
$('.cck').parent().addClass(cck.text());
```

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.cck').each(function() {
    var cck = $(this);
    cck.parent().addClass(cck.text());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gulfarazyasin/5PmF2/)